# $_GET replace some char

Tags: php, get

I want to send a data via `$_GET` and the data look like this
`7U0e1rK6SmjOJuLyAMc5ZL+EsuGqKo2SRSTq3cQlI20=`

and the `$_GET` variable is `voucher_code`

When I tried to echo the `$_GET['voucher_code']`, I always ended up with

`7U0e1rK6SmjOJuLyAMc5ZL EsuGqKo2SRSTq3cQlI20=` *notice the "+" is replaced by "space"

How to stop the `$_GET` to do that ? replacing my "+" with "space"

Any reply appreciated

Comment: The space is only added if you are doing urldecode() on the string before echoing it out. You don't need to decode $_GET inputs. They should already be decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve data you are sending, you have to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it first:

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. This differs from the » RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.

Then, when you receive the data, you have to [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it:

```
var_dump(urlencode('7U0e1rK6SmjOJuLyAMc5ZL+EsuGqKo2SRSTq3cQlI20='));
// result is 7U0e1rK6SmjOJuLyAMc5ZL%2BEsuGqKo2SRSTq3cQlI20%3D
var_dump(urldecode('7U0e1rK6SmjOJuLyAMc5ZL%2BEsuGqKo2SRSTq3cQlI20%3D'));
// result is 7U0e1rK6SmjOJuLyAMc5ZL+EsuGqKo2SRSTq3cQlI20=
```

Note, that when you receive the data with `$_GET`, [it already passes `urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).